# What is the purpose of AccountManager (android)?

Tags: android, accountmanager

Does it bypass the need to use OAUTH or OPENID for authentication on an android app?

Answer (score 2):

Purpose of this class it to help organize access and manage accounts stored on particular phone. Those accounts does not have to be connected in any way to some internet accounts/services. Accounts might be used to distinguish different phone users.

Also AccountManager does not provide any ease of authentication methods, you need to make them by yourself and by different class.

Please have a look here

http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-account-manager-step-by-step

and here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html

Comment: Can this be utilized on any device? Logitech revue (Google tv)

Comment: AccountManager is available in standard android SDK above version 6 so yes you can